# How do I get default field value of an object?

Tags: apex, schema

When I try the following:

```
Object defaultValue = MyObject__c.MyField__c.getDescribe().getDefaultValue();
Object defaultValue = MyObject__c.SObject.MyField__c.getDescribe().getDefaultValue();
```

I always get `NULL` in the result. Why?

Comment: may be you are looking for `getDefaultValueFormula()` ?

Comment: @Ratan `getDefaultValueFormula()` doesn't work either.

Comment: You don't mention the type of the fields but FYI https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XL8AAM; using the latest API version would probably be necessary too if this is the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an easy way to get default values for all fields on an SObject

```
Foo__c f = (Foo__c)Foo__c.sObjectType.newSObject(null, true);
```

- The first argument to `newSObject(..)` is the recordType Id
- The second argument, when `true`, says to create the sobject with defaultValues

Then, you can use methods like

```
f.get(Foo__c.MyField__c);  // or ...
f.get(some variable of type SobjectField);  // or ...
f.get('MyField__c');
```

to get the specific default value for a given field

Remember that default values can be formula-based using $User, $Label, $Profile, ... so based on context, the values may vary

Comment: You can cast it to a `Foo__c` record and then do a direct `get` that does not require casting (e.g. `(Foo__c)f.MyField__c` instead of `(String)f.get('MyField__c')`).