# How to get metadata of metadata field types?

Tags: metadata-api, profile

Is it, for example, possible to get information about `Profile.ProfileApplicationVisibility` (like [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm))? Possible requirements are: Which fields are required or what is the default value of that field.

Comment: May be this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/114222/45062 and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/231635/45062 would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is the [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm), specifically the [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) section under Reference.

You'll find information about the type `Profile.ProfileApplicationVisibility` on the page for the [`Profile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) entity. It includes information about the fields on that type and what is required. Where defaults are present on non-required fields, they're also described in that documentation.

You can use the [`describeValueType()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_describeValueType.htm) and [`describeMetadata()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_describe.htm) API calls to get metadata describe information.

Comment: Thank you. What I meant is there programmatically way (API) to get these information?

Comment: Yes, I've added a note on how to do so.

Comment: `describeValueType()` helped me. It returned all required `Profile` fields.

Comment: Update: It doesn't seem to work with all types. For example calling `describeValueType()` 
 with `PermissionSet` doesn't return all fields like documented.